# atoi function in C programming language K&R

Tags: c, for-loop, atoi

I quite don't know what this loop does.

```
int atoi(char s[])
{    
     int i, n;


     n = 0;
     for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)
         n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
     return n;
}
```

This part I don't get:

```
for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)
     n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
```

I get the whole for loop inside parentheses, and what s[i] - '0' does.
But I don't get what kind of operation is going on here --> `n = 10 * n`.

I don't know what n is representing and why is multiplying 10. 
I know it's converting string of digits to numeric equivalent, but I just don't get the whole operation there.

Comment: `=` in C and C-like languages is the assignment operator; it assigns whatever is on the RHS to the variable on the LHS. That is, the RHS is evaluated first, and the results are saved to the LHS. It has nothing to do with mathematical equality.

Comment: Take a string and step through the code line by line in the debugger. You will see what n is.

Answer (score 4):

> But I don't get what kind of operation is going on here --> n = 10 * n

That's just how you build a number digit by digit. It's basically the same as it would work if you were writing a calculator. If I wrote a simple calculator, here's how it would handle the input <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>:

1. Start with 0
2. <kbd>5</kbd> ==> 0*10 + 5 = 5
3. <kbd>4</kbd> ==> 5*10 + 4 = 54
4. <kbd>7</kbd> ==> 54*10 + 7 = 547

Basically, `atoi` does, the exact same thing, but instead of reading each digit from button presses, it's reading them from a string. Each time you read a new digit, you do `n *= 10` to make room for that next digit, which just gets directly added on the end.

Comment: I don't get why you put 5, 4, and 7. Does that mean I could put any numbers I want? I get the mathematical equation though, easy to understand.

Comment: @user3029785 - Yes, that was just an example. It would correspond to how you'd handle the string `"547"` with `atoi`. Work through a few examples by hand and it should make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`n` is the digits that has already been processed. For instance, for the string `"123"`, first, the program gets digit `1`, convert it to integer and store it in `n`, and then get the next digit `2`, this is where `n = 10 * n` is useful, the previous `1` is multiplied by `10`, and added to the next digit `2`, the result is `12`, and this is stored as the current `n`.

The same goes on, when processing `3`, the previous stored `12` is multiplied by `10`, results in `120` and added to `3`, ended as `123` as result.

Comment: /oh, I get it. Thanks.